# JWT Token always expires after 'exp' provided in the claims

Tags: oauth2, authentication, c#, .net, jwt

I've tried implementing a JWT Bearer Token Flow. I followed the documentation on [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_jwt_flow.htm&type=0). The code is originally in Java but I managed to adapt it to c# as the code below shows.

```
        String header = "{\"alg\":\"RS256\"}";
        String claimTemplate2 = "{{\"iss\": \"{0}\", \"sub\": \"{1}\", \"aud\": \"{2}\", \"exp\": \"{3}\"}}";
        try
        {
            StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder();

            //Encode the JWT Header and add it to our string to sign
            token.Append(Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(header)));
            // ourstring.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

            //Separate with a period
            token.Append(".");


            //Create the JWT Claims Object
            Object[] claimArray = new Object[4];
            claimArray[0] = "client_id";
            claimArray[1] = "email@email.com";
            claimArray[2] = "https://login.salesforce.com";
            claimArray[3] = ((DateTimeOffset.Now.ToUnixTimeMilliseconds() / 1000) + 300).ToString(); // (300)5min expiration


            //String payload = String.Format(claimTemplate, claimArray[0], claimArray[1], claimArray[2], claimArray[3]);
            String payload = String.Format(claimTemplate2, claimArray);


            //Add the encoded claims object
            token.Append(Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload)));

            //Load the private key from a keystore

            KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

            keystore.load(new FileInputStream("C:/file.jks"), "pass".ToCharArray());

            PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey)keystore.getKey("certalias", "pass".ToCharArray()); 

            Debug.Print(privateKey.ToString());

            //Sign the JWT Header + "." + JWT Claims Object
            Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
            signature.initSign(privateKey);
            signature.update(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token.ToString()));
            String signedPayload = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(signature.sign());

            //Separate with a period
            token.Append(".");

            //Add the encoded signature
            token.Append(signedPayload);

            return (token.ToString());
```

The problem that I have is when I test JWT token, it works fine however it never repects the 5min (or 2.5min I also tested) I give in the claims parameter as an expiration time, it takes about 10min +, I'm not sure why. I'm not sure where the problem is coming from? Maybe something in my code isn't right after changing it from java I might have changed something?

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[RFC7523](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7523#section-3.4), which defines JWT authentication, specifies in  section 3.4  that

> The authorization server MUST reject any JWT with an expiration time that has passed, *subject to allowable clock skew between systems.*

(Emphasis mine). The allowable clock skew grants your system a bit of leeway to utilize the token if its own clock is running behind the server's, or vice versa.

As far as I am aware, the length of "allowable clock skew" is at the implementor's discretion, and I don't believe the allowable clock skew for Salesforce's server is documented explicitly. At least one party other than Salesforce uses an allowable clock skew of as much as five minutes.

Comment: Okay I see, is there a way I could maybe modify that clock skew somehow or do I have to just work with it?

Comment: @dotname No, it's defined by the server. You can't change it and shouldn't rely on it being any specific value.

Comment: Alright thank you very much